# How to optimise python random function

Tags: python, random, python-3.x

I want to generate random number between 0 to 3.8 million in python but it takes 1 second to generate such number, so is there any good way to generate it in a faster way ?

```
from random import randint

randomIndex = randint(1, 3800000)
print randomIndex
```

This is tacking 1 second, not every time, but sometimes so I want to optimize it so is there any solution ?

Also some good algorithm ?

Comment: If it's working fine then better post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: If things take 1 second, then that's *not* in the call to `randint()`. Is your machine taxed with other things? Is it swapping perhaps?

Comment: Running this 1 million times with the `timeit` module takes under 2 seconds on my machine. This is *not* a python problem. Python 3.3 is a *little* slower than that, but nowhere near the timings you claim.

Comment: Note that the calculation is constant in time independent of the size of the range. A larger range does not lead to longer calculation times.

Comment: Confirmed, this takes microseconds on my machine: `>python -mtimeit "from random import randint" "randint(1, 3800000)"` gives `100000 loops, best of 3: 3.42 usec per loop`.

Comment: If others were confused like me: [lac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) is "*a unit in the South Asian numbering system equal to one hundred thousand*".

Comment: Perhaps you're including the time it takes to start up the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to speedup your code, you can try to use `numpy` package.

On my system, random give me:

```
$ python -mtimeit "from random import randint" "randint(1, 3800000)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.14 usec per loop
```

And numpy:

```
$ python -mtimeit "from numpy import random" "random.randint(1, 3800000)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.6 usec per loop
```

With a ~2.5x speedup.